# By Next js Mongoose Required true validation not working

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I am trying out Nextjs and using Mongoose to save a document to MongoDB but my validation for name which I set to `required: true` is not working. That is if I send data without required field also this will insert data in the MongoDB database. Please help!

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from "mongoose";

const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Email is required !!"],
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Password is required !!"],
    },
    about: String,
    profileURL: String,
});

// Model of the above schema
export const User = mongoose.models.users || mongoose.model("users", userSchema);
```

Comment: You just have `name: String` with no required set. Am I wrong?